# archivo batch me sale error al ejecutarlo en el cmd

Tags: archivo, cmd, batch

Me sale error "No se esperaba : en este momento."
El código es el siguiente:

```
@echo off

:inicio
if "%1" == "" (
    echo        MENU
    echo Opcion 1: Accion 1
    echo.
    echo Opcion 2: Accion 2
    echo.
    echo Opcion 3: Accion 3
    echo.
    echo Opcion 4: Salir
    
    set /p opcion=Seleccionar opcion(1,2,3,4):
    goto accion
) else (
    %opcion%=%1
)


echo        MENU
echo Opcion 1: Accion 1
echo.
echo Opcion 2: Accion 2
echo.
echo Opcion 3: Accion 3
echo.
echo Opcion 4: Salir


:accion
if "%opcion%" == "1" (
    echo.
    echo Realizando accion correspondiente a opcion 1
    goto validacion
) else if "%opcion%" == "2" (
    echo.
    echo Realizando accion correspondiente a opcion 2
    goto validacion
) else if "%opcion%" == "3" (
    echo.
    echo Realizando accion correspondiente a opcion 3
    goto validacion
) else if "%opcion%" == "4" (
    echo.
    echo    Has seleccionado salir
    echo Fin de Script
    pause > nul
) else (
    echo Opcion incorrecta
)
:validacion
echo Desea realizar otra accion (S/N):
set /p sino=

if /i "%sino%"=="S" (
    goto inicio
) else (
    echo Fin de Script
    pause > nul
)
```

Comment: Si necesitas verificar si una cadena está vacía, es mejor usar corchetes `[%1]==[]`

Answer (score 0):

El error ocurre en la línea `set /p opcion=Seleccionar opcion(1,2,3,4):`. Puedes averiguarlo quitando el `@echo off`.

Para solucionar el problema debes rodear el mensaje de comillas dobles. Así:

```
set /p opcion="Seleccionar opcion(1,2,3,4):"
```

---

También puedes usar [`choice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/choice) en su lugar. Puedes obtener la posición de la opción elegida con `%errorlevel%`. Por ejemplo:

```
choice /c 1234 /n /m "Seleccionar opcion(1,2,3,4):"
```